# Has a team ever had five all-stars from the previous season on its roster?

Tags: basketball, nba

Since they signed Boogie Cousins, the Golden State Warriors will have five all-stars from the previous season on their roster.

Has this happened before? If not, has a team ever had 5 all-stars on their roster from any point of a player's career other than the 2004 Lakers (Shaq, Kobe, Malone, Payton, Grant)?

Answer (score 1):

1975-1976 Celtics had five from the [1975 All-Star Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975_NBA_All-Star_Game).

[1975–76 Boston Celtics season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1975%E2%80%9376_Boston_Celtics_season)   Cowens, Havlicheck, Scott ([Phoenix Suns in '74-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974%E2%80%9375_Phoenix_Suns_season)), Silas, and White.